# Python: Append Data on Worksheet without deleting the other worksheets in the Workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a master Excel Workbook and want to append data to the first sheet. Atm I can combine multiple excel sheets. This combined excel sheet data should append to the excel master. But if I try to append all other worksheets in the workbook a gone. I tryed so many things openpyxl, pyexcel, Pywinauto but nothing worked for me.

```
import os, glob, pyexcel, xlrd, xlwt
import pandas as pd

print ("PLease enter Path")
Log_input = input("")
Logs = []
xlsfile = ('*')
for name in xlsfile:
   Logs.extend(glob.glob(Log_input + xlsfile))
print (Logs)

print ("Create excel sheet")

#Logs Auslesen
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in Logs]
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None,) for x in excels]
#Erste Zeile Entfernen
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]
#Excel File Mergen
combined = pd.concat(frames)
#File Schreiben
combined.to_excel("C:\\temp.xlsx", sheet_name='First', header=False, index=False)
```

#Here I want to append the created worksheet to the master

Comment: I think the problem is related to using `to_excel()` with a filename which will always create a new file. Pandas has a concept of using ExcelWriter objects if you want to work with existing files. Otherwise openpyxl 2.4 includes explicit support for Pandas' Dataframe objects.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21764876/3648361) is already complete enough to make it several ways.

Comment: Yeah it helped a bit. But the suggested mode='a' for appending data wont work. TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'