# Can we copy a dataframe, with rows and cols >1, into an excel sheet?

Tags: python, pandas, win32com

Here's the code I am using

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('myWorkbook.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[11,22,33,44,55], 'C':['a','b','c','d','e']})
wb.Sheets('Template').Copy(Before=None, After=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count))

ws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
ws.Range(ws.cells(40,19), 40+len(df.index)-1, 19+len(df.columns)).Value = df.values
```

But I always receive the following error:
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

Comment: Why would you do this with COM?  pandas writes to excel natively

Comment: @user1558604 Yes, but the actual code is in a loop. In that it is copying multiple dataframes. But to me it gives the ValueError, I cant understand why.

Comment: I'm not sure how being in a loop affects the fact that pandas can write to excel itself without COM. I can't help with excel COM because honestly I can't think of any reason to do it that way. If you post the full error and trace others may be able to help.

Comment: In python, openpyxl is possibly the most commonly used library to interact with excel, and pandas can also write to excel. for interactive use pandas can also put the data frame contents in a clipboard that you can paste where appropriate. I think you will find more support if you were using a more commonly used tool

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Hi @r.ook, I tried with that but as I said I am writing different dfs to sheet, so when i write another the previous df values gets  cleared

Comment: It might be worthwhile to concat your dataframes per sheet and write to excel, provided they are the same structure.  As others said using COM could be quite error prone when an alternative exists.  The best I can think of would be to utilize the `pd.DataFrame.to_clipboard()` method and then paste it with COM, but it's awfully manual.